# Rails ActiveStorage - has_on_attached/has_many_attached associations is load by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I got a problem with ActiveStorage, Currently I have `has_on_attached`and `has_many_attached` relation on my Model

Every time I call my model it loads the relation as below:

`ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (4.2ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 4934], ["record_type", "User"], ["name", "profile_picture"], ["LIMIT", 1]]`

`ActiveStorage::Attachment Exists (0.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 4934], ["record_type", "User"], ["name", "home_pictures"], ["LIMIT", 1]]`

How can I disable this behaviour by default ?

Comment: Do you look https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#attaching-files-to-records ?

Comment: @ClydeT Yes, I haven't seen anything about that

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Model.with_attached_images.find(:id)` to avoid the N+1

https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activestorage#examples

I'm not sure if you can disable eager loading the attachments, but the above should help clean up a little bit.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I found this solution too and it seems to work ;)

Comment: I have the same problem, but I'm using a joins.  Listings have many attachments. School.joins(:listing).where('beds > ?',beds).  How do I eager load attachments in this case, or better yet, not load attachments at all?

Comment: @tomb you might be able to use `Model.select()` to limit the fields that are included/presented (and not include the `with_attached...` syntax as well